# How to apply common java script method for all Button when onclick action occur?

Tags: javascript, jsf, button, xhtml, richfaces

In my Web Application
I need to Apply common java script method for all Button when onclick action occur

For example
For all following buttons need to apply `onclick="commonOnClickJavaScript();"`

```
<h:commandButton id="createCarButton"
    title="Create Car"
    action="#{carController.add}" styleClass="submit_btn" />

<h:commandButton id="editCarButton"
    title="Edit Car"
    action="#{carController.edit}" styleClass="submit_btn" />

<h:commandButton id="createDoorButton"
    title="Create Door"
    action="#{doorController.add}" styleClass="submit_btn" />

<h:commandButton id="editDoorButton"
    title="Edit Door"
    action="#{doorController.edit}" styleClass="submit_btn" />
```

The native solution is taht
To embed `onclick="commonOnClickJavaScript();"` in every button
For example

```
<h:commandButton id="createCarButton"
    title="Create Car"
    action="#{carController.add}" styleClass="submit_btn"
    onclick="commonOnClickJavaScript();" >
```

But in my application
I need to apply that for hundreds of buttons
so this solution will not be simple and waste a lot of time

Any Ideas?

Comment: Use jQuery `$('button').click(commonOnClickJavaScript);` or use Angular.JS and ng-loop to build all your buttons dynamically from an array.

Comment: You could probably override renderer for `commandButton`, make it include `onclick="..."` on every button, but that seems like an overkill.

Comment: @SamMorrowDrums Thanks .. jQuery is the key solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djve/7yf8fuk6/1/), have a selector retrieving all the buttons and a small JavaScript to apply the event listener to all your buttons?

Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" class="myButton" value="Button1">
<input id="Button2" type="button" class="myButton" value="Button2">
<input id="Button3" type="button" class="myButton" value="Button3">


var handleButtonClick = function () {
        alert('Button clicked');
    },
    buttonArray = $('.myButton');

    $.each(buttonArray, function (index, item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            handleButtonClick();
        }, false);
    });
```

Comment: And you can use the jquery selector to select by tag $('h:commandButton') which I guess will work as well.

Comment: `<h:commandButton>` is on server side only, it is rendered as `<input type="button" ...>` on the client side.

Comment: then you can select input type button with the jquery selector instead. $( ":button" )